# Flex4: Detect source Video size VideoPlayer?

Tags: apache-flex, video, size, flex4, flex-spark

Is it possible in Flex 4's VideoPlayer control (spark.components.VideoPlayer) to detect some attributes of the source video?

In my case, it's a local file. I would need to detect the original width and height of the input source video (an h264 f4v).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that info from the videoWidth and videoHeight properties of the video object that is contained within the video player, for example:

```
//Assuming you have your VideoPlayer object with an id of "videoPlayer"
videoPlayer.videoObject.videoWidht;
videoPlayer.videoObject.videoHeight;
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried that.. The width and height is 0.. until I pause the movie, then it takes the right values.. weird. any idea why? is it because it's a local media (file://...) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for a MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE event on the VideoPlayer before accessing this property.  For some strange reason you need to wait until event.state == MediaPlayerState.BUFFERING as its not yet available on MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.READY as you'd probably expect.

Comment: Sorry, after some more experimenting it seems that the dimensions are available on MediaPlayerState.PLAYING, which makes more sense.  Even if autoPlay is false the PLAYING state fires once (immediately followed by a PAUSED state) so you should be able to rely on this happening.